# Make float IMAGE beside DIV?

Tags: css, html, layout, floating

I want the image to float on the left of the green box (see dashed area.)

[image: target position of the image]

How can I achieve that with the markup used here?:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGNbbB

---

I expected the following CSS to do the job. But this dies not work:

```
#content article {float: left;}
```

Comment: `#content-wrapper #content article img { float: left;
max-width: 20%;
margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;}` try using this, further you can play with `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `width`of your `.article` to:

```
#content-wrapper #content article {
      width: calc(100% - 250px); }
```

where "250px" is the fixed width of your green box.

And add to your image:

```
img {width:100%;}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/8L1b9dkd/)**